Why is the foundation of a passive portfolio better than active?
Over and over I see advice that passive portfolios generally do better than actively managed ones due to their low fees, and that, for the most part, portfolio managers can't beat the market.
Given this, there doesn't seem to be a solid reason why we shouldn't just do something like dump our money in a company like Wealthsimple and wait it out. However, lately I find myself concerned about the fundamentals of the U.S. as a nation state, and prefer the nimbleness of a portfolio that is dynamic.
That being said I'm curious to know why passive investing is considered the best choice? Is there a scenario where passive investing could become the riskier choice?

"lately I find myself concerned about the fundamentals of the U.S. as a nation state" - Given that (as per your comment below) you are in Canada, I'd say your fund choices should be the least of your concern if your concerns come to fruition...

As bad as things are now, how are they worse than the Great Depression, oil crisis, dot com bubble, etc.? The economy is always going through highs and lows.

@Nosjack a little concerned about politicians like Trump and the way their politics are going. Probably a bit of an irrational concern to avoid the U.S. at this point, but it helps me sleep at night

But that has nothing to do with active vs passive - if you want to avoid US markets there are plenty of active and passive funds that do that.

That's true, I guess I'm looking at the immediately available options I have in Canada which are typically all heavily invested in the U.S.. The brokerage I'm using is actively managed and not heavily invested in the U.S. I guess it would be a matter of doing more research and finding some more portfolios that aren't.

Key search term "Efficient-Market Hypothesis".

It may be worth noting that the active portfolio I'm using comes from Nicola Wealth who isn't trying to beat the market by stock picking. Instead they're heavily invested in alternative products and real estate without a big footprint in equities. Lots of income from dividends. The fees are high but the portfolio is performing pretty well.

Ah yes, "alternative assets". You would expect an illiquidity premium, but it's all too easy mask volatility by marking to whatever the fund manager wants to. Private equity exposure isn't necessarily a bad thing, but how do you know how it's performing except through the marketing material they give you?

I'll note that a hedge fund manager will happily argue that an active portfolia is better than a passive one.  Mind you, when Ted Seides made a $1M bet with Warren Buffet on this topic. he lost.

https://money.stackexchange.com/a/155284/109107 might be helpful.

"nimbleness of a portfolio" implies active trading, and trading involves fees. Not as much as it used to be, but factoring in the cost of buying and selling is also part of the calculation.

@spuck Although true, trading fees are so minimal these days, and many platforms have no trading fees for the most commonly traded equities.  The primary exception seems to be OTC markets.

Not just commissions for buying and selling, but short-term redemption fees, too.

"I find myself concerned about the fundamentals of the U.S. as a nation state." There are a lot of things that you have no control over. If an asteroid hits earth, then yes your stock money might all disappear. If the US collapses, then everyone has more problems to worry about than their stock money.


That being said I'm curious to know why passive investing is considered the best choice?

Because the market is inherently unpredictable and every attempt to predict it market will more often than not be wrong. This has been proven time and time again. Over 90% of all managed funds do worse than the S&P 500 despite the fund managers raking in billions of dollars in fees. With a few exceptions, the 10% who are actually doing better are just luck: given the large number of funds there's got to be some statistical variation.
If a highly paid professional fund manager can't beat the market: how can you?

Is there a scenario where passive investing could become the riskier choice?

The one lever which is still useful is to managing the balance stocks and less volatile investments. But that depends a lot on your details

"every attempt to predict it market will more often than not be wrong" I guess you're being intentionally hyperbolic here, because if what you say was true and you could reliably mispredict what the market will do, why wouldn't you just do the opposite of what the prediction tells you and win big time? :-) In reality, it's more like predicting the market works a little bit, but the excess return from that often isn't enough to pay for the transaction and management costs.

@TooTea: I'm not so sure things are as reversible as you claim, at least when it comes to actual investing rather than on-paper predictions.  For example, it's possible to be wrong on "both sides" by virtue of the spread.

Peter Lynch must have been incredibly lucky. When he ran Fidelity Magellan, he beat the market in 10 out of 12 years. OTOH, he couldn't pick successors who matched his success when he retired.

@Barmar take 1,000 people and ask them to flip a coin 12 times. What's the odds of one of those people getting 10 heads? Are they "lucky" or just a statistical outlier?

@DStanley Could the lucky one write a book explaining how they did it? And even bad investing is not generally random like coin flips.

@Barmar: I'm sure that, with enough (writing) talent, they could. Especially if there are enough potential readers with a deeply held wish to believe that it's possible to learn to be good at coin flipping and become rich that way. (This should not be taken as any kind of assertion about the possibility or impossibility of a skilled investor consistently beating the stock market. I'm just saying that even if it was actually impossible, a sufficiently charismatic person who just got lucky with the market could still easily spin it into a success story. And probably sell a lot of books.)

@IlmariKaronen Is that a general statement, or are you commenting specifically on Lynch's books that explain his investing strategy?

@Barmar: Yes, it's a general statement. I've never read Lynch's books, so there's no way I could possibly comment on them specifically.

@DStanley in active investing you make a lot more than 12 trades in 12 years, or even 12 trades a year. That analogy breaks down. I don't know how many trades Peter Lynch has placed in his lifetime, but it could easily be in the tens of thousands. If someone flips a coin ten thousand times and gets ten thousand heads (I am sure Peter Lynch was never 100% right either by the way), would you still say it's luck or a statistical outlier?

@Allure 10/12 successful years =/= 10k correct trades; for all we know, all trades but a handful of big ones per year were failures.

@falsedot then you'd have to flip a different kind of coin - the kind which determines how many eggs to put into each basket.

Anyone who thinks "beating the market" is a 50-50 thing should prove it by managing several virtual portfolios. Even if every single stock is 50-50 to go up or down (is it really?) there's still things like when to take profit, when to cut loss, and how much money to put into each stock.

Can you please add the source for the claim that "over 90% of all managed funds do worse than the S&P 500"?

@EndAntisemiticHate: the numbers quoted vary (quite a bit) by source, method , time period and bias, but you can start here https://www.nerdwallet.com/article/investing/index-funds-vs-mutual-funds. Granted it puts the number (over the last 15 years) at 88% and not at 90%+

Thank you for the helpful link.  If you find any additional good ones, please feel free to cite them as well.  As you mentioned, avoiding bias in such articles will be the biggest challenge, as an author can intentionally pick any time period just to make a point.  Thus, a link that shows multiple time periods would be fantastic.

@EndAntisemiticHate: its easy enough to Google and you can review the sources to focus in on the specific metrics and time periods you are most interested in

You seem to believe that an active portfolio reduces risk because it can adapt to avoid "bad things" whereas a passive portfolio just blindly follows some arbitrary index and therefore would succumb to the "bad things".
But that assumes that the person making the decision can wisely make the right investing decisions to avoid the bad things, while not making bad choices that avoid "good things". History has shown that the people making those decisions do not make good enough decisions on average to overcome the cost of paying them to make those decisions. So while there may be cases where an active portfolio performs better, on average they do not perform better (after additional costs are considered) than a passive portfolio.

lately I find myself concerned about the fundamentals of the U.S. as a nation state

So then don't focus on US investments. Buy funds (active or passive) that focus on international companies, fixed income funds, etc. to reduce your exposure to the US market.
EDIT
After rereading your comments on other answers, I would add to my answer that active vs passive should not be a primary investment decision - meaning if you want to avoid the US market and active funds are your only choice, there's nothing wrong with using active funds.
In other words, it's better to use active funds in the segments that you want to investment in versus using passive funds that target markets you want to avoid.

I disagree with most of the other answers so far. It's absolutely possible to "beat the market" with an actively-managed portfolio, that's why an entire profession exists to do it. It's also why there are examples of such successful managers in history (example).
However, 1) it's really, really hard, and 2) the bigger you get, the harder it is to beat the market. It's why Buffett is on the record for saying he can make 50% returns a year on $1 million (but give him a much larger sum like $100 billion and that's no longer possible).
With that in mind:

Why is passive investing considered the best choice?

There are several reasons for this.

Because it's really, really hard to beat the market, people who can beat the market are in very high demand. That means they charge high fees, which means it cuts into your returns (you earn less, after fees). It's very possible that you actually earn less after fees from an active fund than you would have from a passive fund.
Besides, past performance is not a guarantee of future success. A fund can beat the market many decades in a row and then implode spectacularly. Humans are fallible, and if you are right over a long period of time, it's possible you come to believe that you are "always right", which is very dangerous (another example). This means any active investment is riskier: you are more likely to make more money, but there's also a nonzero chance of losing a lot.
On a personal level, when you manage actively you also make more trades. More trades means more commissions paid to the broker, so the bar you need to clear is already higher.
Finally, managing actively takes time and effort. Trawling through annual reports, watching Bloomberg TV, etc., becomes a necessity, not a luxury. Even if the individual trades are easy things that can be done in a few minutes, the thought process behind the trade is not. There is a reason why fund management is a full-time job. Are you willing to invest the time?

In short, assuming you don't want to invest the time (#4), and also assuming that you cannot risk losing most of your money (#2), then passive investing becomes the best choice. Otherwise active investing can be better.

Is there a scenario where passive investing could become the riskier choice?

Riskier than what? Passive investing is always going to be riskier than bonds (since the US economy going into a recession is significantly more probable than the US defaulting on its debts).
If on the other hand you're asking if passive investing could become riskier than active investing, then the answer is broadly "no". In general, the way to reduce risk is to diversify - that is, to invest in many different companies at the same time. Index investing provides automatic diversification, making it one of the least risky ways to invest. If you're investing actively, it's improbable you can stay up-to-date on hundreds of stocks at the same time, so you can't get as much diversification.

Plus one but could be improved by mentioning fees - you either pay a market-beater such big fees as to negate their advantage, or you spend the time yourself

Nice answer, all points seem correct to me. Just a little heads-up, I believe when people say that nobody can beat the market, they basically mean what you are saying - it is very hard, high effort, high cost, reserved to special individuals, and after all of that still not a certainty. Think of it like "people cannot beat the market easily and guaranteed (and certainly not random laypersons)". At least that's my meaning when I use the shorter form. Exceptions notwithstanding.

One thing to be clear about is that while there are almost always some active managers who beat the market over some period, the list of active managers who have done this reliably over long periods (e.g. decades) is very small.  A big mistake people make is to keep moving their money into the funds that did well last year.

The foundation for passive investments is the knowledge that one cannot accurately predict the market.  How many times have you watched the news, and they say something like "these conditions have shocked the experts".  Those statements apply to everything from weather, to butter prices, to stock market activity.
In other words, the experts don't know along with everyone else.
So there is a case that can be made for passive investments that follow an index.  Many indexes are dynamic, such as the S&P500 fund.  Stocks are added and dropped a couple of times per year.  A fund that follows such an index is dynamic.
Some actively managed funds are more dynamic, but they may be wrong.

we shouldn't just do something like dump our money in a company like Wealthsimple

This is something that I don't understand.  Why is the new, sexy companies more attractive than those with a long track record.  I would ask the opposite question:
Why would you invest with a company like Wealthsimple when companies like Fidelity and Vanguard are free for everyone to use?
Both Vanguard and Fidelity offer low cost index funds and ETFs.  Both offer rebalancing services, research, free trades, seminars, and if you want a managed portfolio.  Given their track record and size it is hard for companies such as Wealthsimple to compete.
For example, one can buy brokered certificate of deposits from either Vanguard or Fidelity.  Say you have some money that you will not need for 6 months or so.  You can stick it in your online savings account that might (currently) be paying 4%.  Instead you could buy CDs with a few clicks paying 4.5%.  Or if you are feeling like things will be okay in the short term, you could also buy junk bonds paying almost 6%.
So in my mind, checkout the Vanguard and Fidelity website and see which one you like the best.

Can't sign up for Vanguard as I'm in Canada

From Google:  Yes, Fidelity Investments is available in Canada. or Yes, Charles Schwab is available in Canada.  Schwab is pretty darn good too.

Wealthsimple make it very easy to dip your toe in with a managed account, and then once you're comfortable enough to switch to managing things yourself I don't see a great reason to switch to another platform unless you're doing something more complex than buying & holding ETFs. WS's cash account is currently at 4.25% (if you have 100k in assets with them & >$2k/month direct deposit), and are rolling out a credit card with 2% cashback

Which is not to shill for them, I suspect they're still in the newcomer stage of offering quite good deals in order to build a large userbase and they will get worse eventually. But as of right now I don't really see an advantage for a relatively inexperienced investor with a simple portfolio to switch from them


However, lately I find myself concerned about the fundamentals of the
U.S. as a nation state, and prefer the nimbleness of a portfolio that
is dynamic.

Passive doesn't mean invested 100% in one market.
There are many indexes that can used. Some focus on a big broad market, others in a region of the world , and still others aren't even tracking stocks because they are 100% bonds.
You decide the mix of funds that makes sense for your situation, and you periodically make adjustments to the mix. You also periodically re-balance your investments.
The passive funds don't spend large sums of money doing research because they just follow the index. Over the decades the makeup of an index changes, and the funds follow along. The index funds don't feel a need to make trades just to show action, which also keeps their costs down, and is more tax efficient.

Ok so I guess the ideal way to do passive would be to do it myself as an 'active investor with a passive portfolio'. Makes sense. Then I guess my issue is that I prefer to be a 'passive investor' (where an actively managed portfolio might make more sense as it reduces risk).

@Cdn_Dev I don't know what you mean by "active investor with a passive portfolio," and active management doesn't necessarily reduce risk. I think you have some misconceptions that D Stanley's answer addresses.

"Active" means you regularly invest your personal time into the issue, checking things out, buying, selling, trying to beat the market and so forth. "Passive" means you make a decision and stick with it long-term. Deciding once that you want to invest 33% in a U.S. index, 33% in, say, Germany; and 33% in Japan, and then sticking with that decision "forever" is passive (as far as you as private investor are concerned), and still diversified. @Cdn_Dev

@AnoE This is worth it's own answer, instead of a comment

@mishan, done...

@AnoE yes I'm a passive investor in the sense that I don't want to spend my life thinking about investing. But I've invested in a robo-investor / portfolio that is active.. people are involved managing it. From my perspective I'm passive, but the portfolio I'm invested in is active. If I was 'active' and paying more attention I could likely put together or find a solid passive portfolio that works for me.

Running an "active" portfolio means that you, as a person, regularly invest your personal time into the topic, researching companies or markets, buying, selling, trying to beat the market and so on and forth.
"Passive" means you make a decision and stick with it long-term, say for at least a year, realistically longer. You'd only come back to investing when you do rote regular tasks, i.e. regularly moving money piling up in your bank account into your pre-determined stocks.
Deciding once that you want to invest 33% in a U.S. index, 33% in, say, Germany, and 33% in Japan; and then sticking with that decision "forever" is passive (as far as you as private investor are concerned), and still diversified.
The same goes for the people managing your fonds/ETFs - they only "once and for all" decide to follow index XYZ, and never go on a search for some better investment. They just regularly buy and sell according to the decisions imposed on them by their index.
Speaking of yourself as a private lay person; unless you are a finance buff, or treating this as a high-risk gambling hobby, experience shows that the you have very little chance to regularly beat the market with any degree of certainty. And for professionals, the same is true - but for them, we have survivorship bias, only ever seeing the very few who, by chance, somehow did beat the market. This is the reason why people say that doing this passively is "better" than actively.

I think the OP is talking about actively-managed funds versus index funds, not manging their own portfolio actively.

I think so too, @Barmar, I'm speaking for both cases (in the 4th paragraph). I.e. explain how doing it active is unlikely to return good results both for OP himself, as well as for a professional fund manager (it being basically just a difference of scale, not principle).

@Barmar professionals get it wrong quite often too, and at a larger scale than individuals (simply because they handle larger volumes and more numerous transactions). And that despite having access to more accurate data and faster trading mechanism (most larger investment firms are their own brokers for example).

@jwenting I've also heard that there's an issue with 'closet indexing' where managers are charging high fees to essentially mirror an index. That's basically a scam in my book.

Passive vs Active
Passive investing is considered best for most investors because markets are highly efficient. This means that information about the world is incorporated quickly into prices (sometimes in the order of microseconds), since market participants have a strong financial incentive to buy low and sell high. Your run-of-the-mill active fund manager is not going to be "nimble" enough to make investment decisions faster than high-frequency trading algorithms.
Market participants are trading to try to get an edge on each other, but in aggregate they will get the same market return passive investors get. Active investing means you'd be picking a fund manager with the hopes they can do better than half of the money invested in the market, most of which held by sophisticated institutional investors, by a large-enough margin to cover their high fees.
90% of funds don't outperform their benchmarks over 15-year timespans, and those that do rarely do it again in the next 15 years, so even that outperformance can be attributed to luck. That means your choice of active manager is essentially random, and you have less than 50% chance of outperforming. You can see then why getting a guaranteed "average" return (minus low fees) from a passive fund can be the best option.
US investments
You express concern about the fundamentals of the United States. But again, markets are efficient. Concerns about US institutions are already priced in to the market. Emerging market stocks, for example, will generally have lower price-to-earning ratios than developed market stocks, partly in response to their shakier legal protections. If new systemic issues with US financial markets come to light, the market will reflect that in prices very quickly.
So what? Maybe you disagree with the market. Well, that's a dangerous path for us small individual investors. The same way we can't pick which individual stocks will outperform better than chance, the same applies to countries. We work with limited information, emotions, and cognitive biases.
As a side note, it's worth noting that companies listed on US stock exchanges are not 100% reliant on doing business in the US. Most of them are multi-nationals selling globally, just like there are European-listed companies with US sales.
Rather than miss out on 63% of the global equity market, I would take my biases out of the equation and invest in countries in proportion to their market cap with a global equity fund like VT. In Canada, you might need to piece this together from multiple funds (and possibly consider possible the tax advantages of overweighting Canadian stocks), but using the same general principle.
